# Como pesquisar e localizar perguntas "fechadas"?

Tags: suporte

Se eu pesquisar por `[fechada]`, com as chaves, irá buscar pela *tag* [fechada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fechada) e assim não traz nada.

Se eu usar `fechada` sem chaves trará tudo contendo essa palavra, mas não as perguntas de fato fechadas.

- Existe uma forma de fazer esta pesquisa?
- Tem solução similar para `[duplicada]`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se você clicar na pesquisa, aparecerá o link **Pesquisa Avançada** contendo os principais argumentos a serem usados na pesquisa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segundo a propria seção:

> Status
>   **closed:yes**
>   duplicate:no
>   migrated:no
>   wiki:no
>   deleted:no

### Exemplo:

Pesquisa de perguntas fechadas na tag [c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) contendo a palavra "método":

> [`método [c#] closed:yes`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=m%C3%A9todo+%5Bc%23%5D+closed%3Ayes)

<sup><sub>clique na expressão destacada acima para ver funcionando, tem link ;)</sub></sup>

Comment: Estou sempre a aprender coisas novas haha! Já ca ando ao tempo e nunca tinha reparado nisso vê lá!

Comment: Nossa, em todos esse anos nessa indústria vital, é a primeira vez que vejo isso :P